# What does red highlight mean in ZSH?

Tags: zsh

I'm confused by the appearance of some directories in Zsh. As shown in figure below:

[image]

What does the red box mean?

Comment: Red? One of us is color-blind, and my color meter says it isn't me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ls -l   will show you properties of the file, and you can adjust the colors,  But out of the box on OSX,  red should be a symbolic link.  You can verify with

```
ls -l  /Volumes/MacMain
```

and it should show as a symlink to /